# Could you help me understand what a problem domain is and how can I build my class diagram based on it?

Tags: class-design, software, class-diagram

So I just started studying Software Engineering because I am really interested in it and my professor in London asked us to create an app which is like Instagram (only theoretically, without the actual implementation of code) and I would like some help on something.

I have started with writing and studying different parts, like risk analysis and everything and now I just created a class diagram with the classes that are in my opinion essential for the project. Like content, photos, users, display, etc. What I really haven't understood is that we needed to draw the class diagram based on the problem domain of my case.

Maybe it's because of my lower English level, but problem sounds literal to me and while some websites mention that the problem domain relates to the risks and the problems of your project, others say that the problem domain is whatever is essential for the creation of the app.

Can someone please elaborate on that? You will really help me get deeper into the project because it's very confusing and they haven't explained it so much at uni yet..

Thanks :)

Comment: Read Eric Evans' *Domain-Driven Design.*  Martin Fowler wrote a description of the book [here](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/DomainDrivenDesign.html).

Comment: Or, if you'd like something a bit more accessible, try [Domain-Driven Design, Quickly](https://www.infoq.com/minibooks/domain-driven-design-quickly/).  There's a free downloadable version available at that link.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Why do you think *"relating to the risks and the problems of a project"* contradicts *"whatever is essential for the creation of the app"*? Or is your question more about the idea of drawing class diagrams for capturing some aspects of a problem domain?

Comment: @DocBrown I think that you're right, I should rephrase the question. I know how to create the class diagrams, but it's more about what a problem domain is. Does it have to do with problems that may occur in my project? With everything that needs to be taken into account in order to have a decent software? With everything that has to do with my project? So it's more about the definition of the problem domain. Apparently I haven't understood it!

Comment: The problem domain is that collection of reasons that are the motivation for building the application in the first place.  Need to automate your sales process?  That's your problem domain.  Need to manage your inventory?  That's your problem domain.  Need to land a rover on Mars?  That's your problem domain.

Comment: @NewbieSoftwarer: as you mentioned an "app like Instagram": here the "problem domain" is media sharing / social media. Part of the domain is how users can share fotos to other groups and the world, a "follow" mechanics, messages to fotos/videos, a search mechanics, advertisement, and things like that. Those topics are somehow connected to the risks and the problems of your project (like financial risks, scaling risks when the platform becomes successful, legal risks with person-related data like portrait fotos).

Comment: "problem sounds literal to me" - here, "problem" is not used in the narrow sense of "some problem you may run into"; it's more general. When you are making an application, you are addressing *some need*. You're providing a *solution* that helps people do something. They might want to do or achieve something, but they don't have the appropriate tools. You can provide them with such a tool - an application. So in one sense, you're solving someone's *problem* 1/2

Comment: In another sense, in order to provide such a tool/solution, in order to build it in the first place, you have to understand their needs, and solve *a set of problems* stemming from these needs/requirements. So it's not "problems that may occur in my project"; a *problem domain* is just what your software is supposed to do, what it's *for*. Take Robert Harvey's Mars rover example. *What* do you need to write? What *are* the problems that the rover mission will face that can be addressed by your software? E.g. how do you solve the problem of recognizing minerals in photos of martian soil? 2/2

Comment: In other words "problem" is not used in the sense of "an issue with the project", but more in the sense of "an intellectual puzzle to solve" (that may or may not partially draw on preexisting solutions, depending on how novel the problems are).

Comment: @FilipMilovanović amazing answer. I appreciate it. :) Understood everything!